# jQuery: Bind JS Function to all Selected Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I'm sure this is a simple question, but didn't see applicable answers here. I've got code like this:

```
 $('.thumbImg').mouseout(function(){selectCur()});
//selectCur() is a pure-JS function defined elsewhere in the document
```

But the function is only bound to the first element with class `.thumbImg`. Normally, I'd use a `$(this)`, but that won't work here (unless I'm doing something wrong).

I guess my last resort is a for loop, but I'm sure there's a way to avoid that.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is probably in `selectCur()`. That code *does* bind the handler to all .thumbImg's.

Comment: Right you are. I had myself a good, old-fashioned, cache problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think it's a cache problem, it's a context problem. Fix it by passing in $this to your selectCur.

```
$('.thumbImg').mouseout(function(){selectCur($(this))});
```

Or even

```
$('.thumbImg').mouseout(selectCur);
```

Then selectCur can use $(this); I think the first solution is better since selectCur could be used from other places, so you can just pass in the node when necessary.

Comment: I'm using you first line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason `this` doesn't work is that it's local to the `function() {}` in your code, not the `selectCur()` function.

If you want to use `this` in `selectCur()`, you can do it like:

`$('.thumbImg').mouseout(selectCur);`

The way you do it is make an anonymous function / closure that calls your function and refer to that in mouseout. Instead of this, all you need to do is point to your function (not call it, no `()` in here) and it'll be called when the event fires. You don't need a function to point to a function. Just point to it and it'll work.